# Create A Batch File from a Notepad to CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file that automatically runs the code in cmd see the picture below

The 1st cmd is a batch file that got error while the 2nd cmd is a manually type in cmd and executes the codes.

This is the code in notepad/batch file

```
cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files\Nvidia Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,timestamp,power.draw,clocks.sm,clocks.mem,clocks.gr --format=csv -l 1"
```

Edit:
I want to run this batch file in desktop because I don't want to manually go to the folder of the .exe and paste the code (waste of time) so that's why I like to create a batch file that i'll run in desktop

[image: This Picture]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. We can't copy-past from an image.

Comment: @mypetlion Sorry, I already include the codes in my post

Comment: **`>`** is an invalid character in a Windows file or directory name. Perhaps you're wanting to run this command inside your window, `"%ProgramFiles%\Nvidia Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi" --query-gpu="index,timestamp,power.draw,clocks.sm,clocks.mem,clocks.gr" --format=csv -l 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files\Nvidia Corporation\NVSMI>nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,timestamp,power.draw,clocks.sm,clocks.mem,clocks.gr --format=csv -l 1"
```

you misinterpreted the first part `C:\Program Files\Nvidia Corporation\NVSMI>` (which is the prompt) with a part of the command.

Either call the program with it's full path:

```
    cmd /K "C:\Program Files\Nvidia Corporation\NVSMI\nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,timestamp,power.draw,clocks.sm,clocks.mem,clocks.gr --format=csv -l 1"
```

or `cd` to the correct folder and `&` execute the program from there:

```
    cmd /K "cd /d C:\Program Files\Nvidia Corporation\NVSMI & nvidia-smi --query-gpu=index,timestamp,power.draw,clocks.sm,clocks.mem,clocks.gr --format=csv -l 1"
```

In both cases, look what I`ve done with the`>`

Comment: Thanks you did it thank you! I dont think it's ok to use '&' in cmd thank you!

Comment: @Liza `&` is completely ok in cmd (depends on what you need). [Reference](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)